# How to check NullvalueException in controllerTest with request param as a string (Spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have to check NullvalueException in ControllerTest(spring,java).
In the function @requestParam is a String.
I test the Controller in this way,but it fails

`when(ServiceImpl.getAllByName(null)).thenThrow(new NullValueException(message));
mockMvc.perform(get("/tag/tag?name=null").
contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
.andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$.fetchresponseList", IsNull.nullValue()))`

Error:
java.lanag.assertionFailure 
status expected was 200 but was 400

Can anyone please tell me why it fails?